# Visual Studio 2010 error linking Winsock library (C)

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, winsock, winsock2

I'm trying to build a C server program, and I keep getting these errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQFuN.png

The common fix I'm seeing is to link to ws2_32.lib, which I'm doing already(Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies). I've also included WinSock2.h. I have the windows sdk, and I get no errors saying it can't find ws2_32.lib. I've tried linking directly to the .lib in the windows sdk directory, but still have the same problem. The dll is in correct place (C:\Windows\SysWOW64), and the SysWOW64 directory is listed in Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Executable Directories.

I have the same problem with Visual Studio 2013

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What does it show as the full command to `cl.exe`?

Comment: You mean this?  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:prompt ..\..\..\..\..\Downloads\XEL\spssls.c